# Server gives message: The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship

Tags: windows-server-2008

I upgraded 25 laptops from xp Pro to 7 Pro (installed on one and imaged the rest using new SID and unique names) All were able to log on to the domain as administrator but as normal users tried logging on to domain they got the message

> "The security database on the server does not have a computer account
>   for this workstation trust relationship"

so I tried removing them from the domain and joining them again and even removed the computers from Active Directory but still got same message so then I tried [this](http://virtualcurtis.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/fix-the-security-database-on-the-server-does-not-have-a-computer-account-for-this-workstation-trust-relationship/) only changing the servicePrincipleName to

```
HOST\server01 and 
HOST\server01.smc.local
```

and I got the first three of the laptops logging on to the domain.
The next day I came back to do the rest but when I tried logging on to the virtual server (Server 2008 R2) I got the message

> "The security database on the server does not have a computer account
>   for this workstation trust relationship on the server."

After checking a bit I found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015518)
which suggests to me that the changes I made to the attributes for the 3 laptops in Active Directory caused this problem.
So I'm now wondering if I remove the 3 laptops from the domain, rename them and rejoin the domain will this fix my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the laptops from the domain and ensure the computer object is deleted from AD and replicated appropriately. After, join them back and your problem should go away.

In the future, while imaging *always* use `sysprep`. It'll save you tons of headache.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Nathan. Once I remove them from the domain, you reckon I'll be able to log in to the server to remove them from the AD? I hope so. I'll try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the problem in the situation you are currently facing you could also simply Sysprep each one, preferably with an Answer File with PersistAllDeviceInstalls enabled to prevent drivers from being removed. Alternatively you could also re-image with a Syspreped image if it is more convenient (automated). Removing them from the domain is probably the simplest and fastest solution to solve your immediate issue.

In the future, you might want to consider the [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT)](http://technet.microsoft.com/windows/dn475741). With it you’ll be able to capture a standard reference image, Sysprep, and have it automatically join the domain when deployed. You’ll also be able to deploy over the network, with WDS even without physical media via PXE. You’ll also be able to update that image during deployment, configure drivers for multiple types of hardware, and configure application installation directly through MDT.

Ultimately you can even have one single reference image without any applications, updates, or drivers and have MDT granularly configure drivers, applications, and updating upon deployment. This means your one image can apply to every department or individual in the organization, regardless of which applications they use or system they have, and it will always be up to date.